# How to install or configure C++ 14 for building pytorch

Tags: macos, c++14

I have a 2020 macbook pro with catalina 10.15 on which I installed the latest `Xcode` in May. So it would be unlikely the version is out of date. What then needs to be configured to fix the following when building `pytorch`

```
#error C++14 or later compatible compiler is required to use PyTorch
```

This occurred as part of building `pytorch` via `npm`:

```
npm install @idn/torchjs
```

Comment: clang should have full support for c++14.